# How to typeset the following table in MathJax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, typesetting

I recently encountered while editing posts a table that seems impossible to typeset. The problem is that you have in the first row only two columns and in the second row $5$ columns that you can't compact into a single $1-2-2$ row using the ordinary {|c|c|c|c|}.

> [image: The table in question.]

So how can I typeset it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lot to be found on formatting tables at [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @PeterPhipps I ask on Meta.Math.SE first since it is the best place where you can be sure that  a line of tex code will be correctly generated since they know the Latex packages that are integrated in MathJax.

Comment: In $\LaTeX$, this table would never be typeset in an equation. The non-mathematical table environment has far more support for complex formatting. I attempted to manage that very table in MathJax and gave up—MathJax just isn't made for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such complex tables are not supported by MathJax, and it is outside their intent: it is supposed to be a software package to help the presentation of *Mathematics* on the internet, not a generic typesetting language to replace HTML.

As I answered [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/tabular-in-mathjax?lq=1), tables are potentially supported by MarkDown, the language in which most other parts of the answers and questions are composed. It is unfortunate that to date tables support is not available on the SE sites. Currently the best work around is to use the `code` environment. Please see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73567/155238).